# VBA - convert to date

Tags: string, vba, excel, date-conversion

I have one more time a problem:

I want to convert from Strings to dates in VBA

The Strings look like: YYYY-DD-MM

The date should be like: DD.MM.YYYY

I know, normally you do this with the method cdate(), but it doesn't work here.
I think it's because the structure of the string is bad to convert.

thanks for your help

InformatikBabo

Comment: you want to transform it into another string of a different formatting or do you want a Date object?

Comment: Just wanted to comment that `CDate()` does not appear to work on strings like `"20200109"`. It works on `"2020-01-09"` (with the hyphens), but not on the hyphenless one. I had to break the string up into three parts and then rebuild it with the hyphens to be able to use `CDate()`. I realized just now that I could have converted the string with `Format()` but the larger point is that `CDate()` appears to only work with strings in certain formats.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
Sub Main()

    Dim strDate As String
    strDate = "2013-06-11"

    Debug.Print "Original Date: ", strDate
    Debug.Print "CDate() Conversion: ", CDate(strDate)
    Debug.Print "Format() as String: ", Format(strDate, "DD.MM.YYYY")

End Sub
```

and the Immediate Window shows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

' Try this on for size.

' This is return a strings "date" as the previous day with a different format !!

' Dstring passed equals this format "08/01/2023"
.

```
Function SdateD(byref Dstring) as String
Dim NewDateD 'undefined

    NewDateD = CDate(Dstring) ' This will convert it to #08/01/2023#
    NewDateD = NewDateD - 1 ' now it is #07/31/2023#
    Dstring = Format(Cstr(NewDateD), "m.d.yy") ' it will return the value 7.31.23

End Function
```

I was pulling a date from a MSWord doc.   08/01/2023

Which was the date after the document was created.

I was wanting to change the name of the file to include the actual date.
You can't use "/" in document names as that is the delimiter for directories.

So this works:

```
  RenameFile OriginalFN & ".Docx", OriginalFN & SdateD(Dstring) & ".Docx"
```