# vba, excel - how to add 3 months to a trimmed date

Tags: excel, vba

I am terrible with coding dates - I would like to add 3 months to a trimmed date. How would I go about this? Coding example below

```
Dim AuStart As String
Dim AuEnd As String

AuStart = Trim(HE.CurrentHost.TextRC(10, 19, 8)) 'this would be for example 12/09/19
AuEnd = ??? 'this for example if the AuStart = 12/09/19 should be 3/09/19

HE.CurrentHost.PutText AuEnd, 10, 45
```

Thanks all

Comment: AuStart = 12/09/19 should be 3/09/20   ???

Comment: Use the [VBA function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19815087/4717755) `CDATE` to convert the date string to a real VBA `Date` type. Then use [`DATEADD`](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php) to add three months

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this...

```
AuEnd = Format(DateAdd("m", 3, DateValue(AuStart)))
```

---

Update

You can add the Number Format for the date at the end...

```
AuEnd = Format(DateAdd("m", 3, DateValue(AuStart)),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Excel Hero - this worked almost perfectly except it makes AuEnd = 3/6/2020 and i need it to be in the format of 03/06/2020. Is this doable? Thanks so much

Comment: @Mikey I updated the answer so that the date is produced in the format you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly pass the string as well, but should be in any date format, As third argument of the DateAdd function is a variant variable.

**Three Month ahead of AuStartDate**

```
Format(DateAdd("m", 3, AuStart),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

**Three Month Prior of AuStartDate**

```
Format(DateAdd("m", -3, AuStart),"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

You can Manipulate the date as per your need, This function is Not just limited to this, For More Detail Please check the below link

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function][1]